# Position from atomic number in the periodic table

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, chemistry, physics

Let us consider the following representation of the periodic table.

```
     __________________________________________________________________________
    | | 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 |
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |1|  1                                                                   2 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |2|  3   4                                           5   6   7   8   9  10 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |3| 11  12                                          13  14  15  16  17  18 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |4| 19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |5| 37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |6| 55  56      72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |7| 87  88     104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |8|             57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71 |
    | |                                                                        |
    |9|             89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 |
    |__________________________________________________________________________|
```

## Task

Produce a program that takes an atomic number as input, and outputs the row and column of the element of given atomic number.

For instance, giving the atomic number `1` should produce `1 1` (or `1, 1`, or anything that looks like a vector of two 1s).

## Details

The representation of the periodic table may be represented in various way. The one presented in this challenge does have the following property : Lantanides and Aktinoides are *all* in a dedicated row, hence there is no element that is placed at `6, 3` nor `7, 3`.

You may take a look at the atomic number repartitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#/media/File:Simple_Periodic_Table_Chart-blocks.svg).

The atomic number is at least 1, at most 118.

## test cases

- `1` -> `1, 1`
- `2` -> `1, 18`
- `29` -> `4, 11`
- `42` -> `5, 6`
- `58` -> `8, 5`
- `59` -> `8, 6`
- `57` -> `8, 4`
- `71` -> `8, 18`
- `72` -> `6, 4`
- `89` -> `9, 4`
- `90` -> `9, 5`
- `103` -> `9, 18`

## Scoring

This is code golf, standard rules applies, hence fewer bytes win.

Comment: There are elements placed at `6, 3` and `7, 3` (Lutetium `n = 71` and Lawrencium `n = 103`). In your table are placed at the end of Lantanides and Aktinoides, but they should not be there.
Can you clarify?

Comment: It would probably be clearer if your table was showing the atomic numbers instead of the symbols, which we don't really care about in this challenge.

Comment: Must we index rows and columns by 1, or is 0-indexing allowed?

Comment: @MatteoC. IKAIK, there is multiple ways to represent those ; I based the puzzle on the [representation i know most](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableau_p%C3%A9riodique_des_%C3%A9l%C3%A9ments#/media/Fichier:Tableau_p%C3%A9riodique_des_%C3%A9l%C3%A9ments.svg).
.Arnauld Indeed ; i will edit the answer as soon as possible !
.MatthewJensen By 1 is asked, so by 1 it must be !

Comment: I wonder if matlab has a builtin for this one.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```javascript
n=>[(n+=--n?n<4?33:n<12?43:n<56?53:n<71?90:n<88?39:n<103?76:25:17)/18|0,n%18+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck5DoMwEEDRPqeYJsKWgWDMYhbjQ1BGKRCbiNAYgZUmy9UJVO9L/9m8mq1dp8V6aLp@H9SOqroTZMrzUGMZaSFyLHmoo9M40fFpynUWHEqpRXb@QOg0ycM45ym9cfkJXLxyyfhjH8xKEBTwAhDKQy6PYozC@wLQGtzM3PuzGQn61tR2nXAk1F@arrbNaomgwMCBX@W4MBCktLh89z8) (raw output)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBboMwEETv@Yq9VLEFODiE4BAcq9@QI@VgJSEigjVyUBVU@u10kdqe3tPMaB720z4vvumHCN31Ntd6Rn0qGQY6itBgsTNJkmMht2a3MN2bdGEmzSEmKmWSw9LHicn2@TbNZcY3Uk1xiG9SBbKaa@dZBxrKKgQkyiOhIEpFFgQcvlYA5RjCq6K6ZsiPFLCuHCECuWT/Ok3w7r0dmVRc1E3bsjUArDkvX39bFIM7D77BO@Oit9fzYP3AEvr8Xl0cPl17E627s050tmce9Am8eLgG6YqOfvUDyecf) (builds the periodic table)

Or **76 bytes** if 0-indexing is acceptable:

```javascript
n=>[(n+=--n?n<4?15:n<12?25:n<56?35:n<71?72:n<88?21:n<103?58:7:-1)/18|0,n%18]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczBboMwDAbge5/Cl6mJgLSBMSJKGu0ZemQcorZUVOCgNKqGxp6dmWqn77ct/3f7tI@z78aQoLtcl1YvqI81w0gnCRqs3o3MS6xkatLV/MNkq4U0RUoqZVK53veZyVVZlInkO6nmfYxvUjVL6zwbQEPdxICkPBAVKRWlKOLwswGopxi@Gzq3DPmBFmyop3V@Mc/w6b2dmFRctF3fsy0AbDmvXz8ogjsF3@GNcTHayylYH1hGPb@bs8OH66@idzc2iMGOzIM@ghd31yHVUMl//ELKyx8)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 79 bytes

Inspired by [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248697/87728). I tried to golf it more,  and ended up with this.

```javascript
n=>[(n+=[113,417,1195,5429,6906,8487,9964].find(x=>n<x/96)%96||25)/18|0,1+n%18]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZHBjpswEIbvPMUcsoqtOCQGHJympOqhhz4DQTUizi4r1iAg26wSnj3FxtlmpayUqid@j2e@/x/znL6mTVbnVTtV5Vaed9FZResYqUkUc4/4ASXL5ZIELPQJ4x4jIWWU8GDuJ@4uV1t0iNbq62HGKX7gdOqdTiGeUX6aE/VAeXJeOY5wKEzXQAlQx7so7vhaeroYWOU5o2Psuu73uk7f0AIn7ktaIfSLKAzRGsToqGACrLPtw5H6ncDuc5kr4YjOocbL11jqWXkftwfZ/pvgawTlnzGWhhG8M/4d4YcGwW4jGNOXC70eW1j5cT3KPgGHXmcHhnPwAcxDfRlqMOdW3gmm86CzE7fIdzHYsDX/DwQf3n55GyHcts5fEHabqshbNN6oMXZ3Zf0jzZ5QK5tWk44OQCFbiAnkqtq3BOryN4GsLBKIQHf1zm0/MEOb7QRrOyPI8JlhOJ0gTlY9Jr6e/HswyQ/a6wBToFi3ZqXq7WvZ7Is@BexQldaN/KlaZELgq6YqbRrDM83xvIdHQ0ZboaainS5DZSHdonxEetS4V9q9gm8gNnsvnDMBXwYZZPbB0HiM319ATNfigicmgCtfZf1mOViDDALJQyWzVm4hHh37TJ3@EX2SLsGiX6HDq/Mf)

The outside is the same as Arnauld's answer, but the lookup for what to offset `n` by is different.

If we create a table the same size as the periodic table, where each item is equal to `column + 18 * row - 1 - Z` (where `Z` is the atomic number at that position), we can see some groups emerge:

```javascript
  ||   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
==||=========================================================================
1 ||  17 |                                                                33
  ||-----+                                       +---------------------------
2 ||  33  33                                     |    43  43  43  43  43  43
  ||---------------------------------------------+  +------------------------
3 ||  43  43                                        | 53  53  53  53  53  53
  ||------------------------------------------------+
4 ||  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53
  ||
5 ||  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53  53
  ||         +---------------------------------------------------------------
6 ||  53  53 |    39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39  39
  ||---------+  +------------------------------------------------------------
7 ||  39  39    | 25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25
  ||------------+------------------------------------------------------------
8 ||              90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90  90
  ||-------------------------------------------------------------------------
9 ||              76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76  76
  ||
```

Once we have the right group, we can just add its value to `Z`, then the row will be `(new) Z / 18`, the column `Z % 18 + 1`.

The lookup table `[113,417,1195,5429,6906,8487,9964]` will be more obvious in this solution with a factor of `100`, instead of `96`:

```javascript
n=>[(n+=[117,433,1243,5653,7190,8839,10376].find(x=>n<x/100)%100||25)/18|0,1+n%18]
```

Each item `i` in the list `[117,433,1243,5653,7190,8839,10376]` corresponds to one of the groups such that the group value is `i % 100` and all atomic numbers in the group are less than `i / 100`. I reduced the factor to `96` to save bytes.

---

### Old invalid answer (0-indexed), 76 bytes

```javascript
n=>[(n+=[82,341,999,4573,5825,7151,8403].find(x=>n<x/81)%81-2||7)/18|0,n%18]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZHdjpswEIXveYq5yCq24piY8GOakqoXvegzEFQQcXZZsQYB2WaV8OwpNs42K2WlVL3ieDzznTPmOXvN2rwp6m4uq60476KzjNYxkrMoZmxJXBYQxkKPeK4TEj9c@IS7PCBh6LsJ3RVyiw7RWn492KGPH0L/dHI8bDN@WhA2kw@MJ@eVZaUWg/kaGAFmORfFraWSjiq6RjnW5BhTSr83TfaGfJzQl6xG6BeRGKI1pJOjhBl4vWkfj2zZp5g@V4VMrbS3mPZaKixzjLyPO4BM/03wNYLxzxihZrjvjH9HLAON8G4jPE9d@mo9zzfy43rM@wQcOL0ZGM/uBzAP1GWgwJwbeSeYLdzeTNwi38Xwxq35fyD4@PbhbURKu6Z4QZi2dVl0aLqRU0x3VfMjy59QJ9pOkY4WQCk6iAkUst53BJrqN4G8KhOIQHUNzt0wYKPNdoaVnRZk/NgYTieIk9WAse34evbvQWc/KLcDzIFh1ZxXcgjQiHZfDjlgh@qsacVP2SEdA1811Vnbap5ujhcDPBpTmgrTFeV0GapKQcvqEalR7V4r9xq@QbrZO8HCS@HLKN3cPBmaTvH7G6TzdXrBEx2AilfRvBkOViCNQOJQi7wTW4gnxyFTr37FkKRPcDqs0OPV@Q8)

Comment: The OP replied to 3 people in [1 comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248689/position-from-atomic-number-in-the-periodic-table#comment555764_248689) without pinging you: it does have to be 1-based indexing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I did see that, just haven’t had a chance to update.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
T•3¾§Ue•44вÝ•¨²>Ùö€•Ƶlв+ª˜18‰>Iè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5FHDIuND@w4tD00FskxMLmw6PBfIOLTi0Ca7wzMPb3vUtAbIPbY158Im7UOrTs8xtHjUsMHO8/CK//9NzQE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9oaOHqZ6@k8KhtkoKS/f@QRw2LjA/tO7Q8NBXIMjG5sOnwXCDj0IpDm@wOzzy87VHTGiD32NacC5u0D606PcfQ4lHDBju/wyv@6/wHAA). (You can add [`--debug-stack` as argument to the singular TIO](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5FHDIuND@w4tD00FskxMLmw6PBfIOLTi0Ca7wzMPb3vUtAbIPbY158Im7UOrTs8xtHjUsMHO8/CK//b/Tc3/6@qmpCaVpusWlyQmZwMA) to see all individual steps.)

**Explanation:**

```python
T          # Push 10
 •3¾§Ue•   # Push compressed integer 15829433590
  44в      # Convert it to base-44 as list: [2,7,43,14,16,14,14] 
     Ý     # Convert each inner value to a list in the range [0,value]
 •¨²>Ùö€•  # Push compressed integer 180810357611003
  Ƶl       # Push compressed integer 148
    в      # Convert to base-148 as list: [17,30,48,129,93,147,111]
     +     # Add these to each value of the inner lists at the same positions
 ª         # Append this list of lists, which will first implicitly converts
           # the initial 10 to list [1,0]
  ˜        # Flatten it
   18‰     # Divmod-18 each inner integer
      >    # Increase each integer in each pair by 1
       Iè  # 0-based index the input into this list of pairs
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•3¾§Ue•` is `15829433590`; `•3¾§Ue•44в` is `[2,7,43,14,16,14,14]`; `•¨²>Ùö€•` is `180810357611003`; `Ƶl` is `148`; and `•¨²>Ùö€•Ƶlв` is `[17,30,48,129,93,147,111]`.

Answer (score 4):

## x86 32-bit machine code, <del>39</del> 36 bytes

```
99 42 A9 FE 42 3C 02 76 1A 8D 4A 02 D1 E9 0F AF C9 D1 E1 28 C8 77 ED 4A 42 2C F1 7F 04 42 7B F8 4A 04 03 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVNdj9owEHy2f8VChc4u4ZRAK0E4kKqqfevLPZ0ECDmJE3JyHOokqhHHXy9dJyVHG0XrjxnPzq6TeJLF8fUqqgLY85DRNCRx8pOSXMcgE0vJY3SqJfj2y8LD@P0bFeE7GBdHEMqDKSWvkQRJiZICZGw92CABxjDdUVIdTLcXoG7RqG6BwUHqBlUhqZqolYsV6gkQlCSyyxTdJb2xJsFnpGVQ37l9PZYQvR@rQyKSpGXPqAyJkTXlQ76k@72oa5NHTS33e8aMzI7CFCzgnIMqddaFXNeQMhcFnvmAWVSTSHiq6iQvHw9r6qBC5JpxesZuHISBWkRKbha7TTDfwQrO/mVJSVoaaHU0bgVLHJ5wDOY4G485JXiY/JvWIDFlGtMS4tYW106BGw9OODewXsNs2sIpMAtrCObw9obgGhZuYl0Ov9u6zTpzp0mw21gMmJmQo0HZlA0HgwGM8u7d6qEH2gO8mFNrQapKOvJ/AmhEI3y5q9CZ85c4DFawwLGvr2fYjmEdw7XAtpSujr/6qN6Z692NPuVoqe3APcd56831ZMBn2GLHpna3wh62@oF3Tm@krf4h4kOuJcRlIsOW39vDunGZlHDuNUf@9AUtnFaMNbrKMy0TcNofeco3WAOaucCvQ64ksLZ6336dOdFegWFv3d9U8ba/1oH4RTZGYz/o5Xr9HadKZNV1UsymGPCnXOFRqf4A)

This takes a 32-bit integer in EAX, following the `regparm(1)` convention. It returns two 32-bit integers in EAX and EDX; [this document](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) seems to say that this would be the standard way of returning a structure of two 32-bit integers, but [it apparently doesn't actually work that way](https://tio.run/##PY/BisIwEIbPnacYKkICVrbuzaoP4Vko2TTtBppYkolUxFc3TtnFy/AN83/DjK4GrXNW0aE4lwL6feGuNzRq3mANf9wx76AIhkCWsoG2VUTB/iQybStEMMOkghO1lBIjhaQJJ3xYT8jivXliL5ZGsbqyXo@pM3iI1Nnr9vcEy8gp64WEBxQfP5iYRsIjyzWLxRQ42ItybXFtL77c/Ce284fuS46vTMHjVwPPnF@6H9UQc@W@d1z4yyNvMeMb) (or am I misreading that document?), which is why the linked TIO program is coded differently.

-3 by calculating line lengths instead of hardcoding them.

In assembly:

```
f:  cdq
    inc edx
    .byte 0xA9, 0xFE
a:  inc edx
    cmp al, 2
    jbe e
    lea ecx, [edx + 2]
    shr ecx, 1
    imul ecx, ecx
    shl ecx, 1
s:  sub al, cl
    ja a
    dec edx
b:  inc edx
    sub al, -15
    jg t
    inc edx
    jpo b
    dec edx
t:  add al, 3
e:  ret
```

The main part of the code works as follows:

- If AL ≤ 2 (in the first two columns), jump straight to the end.
- Calculate the length of the current line as \$ \lfloor\frac{\textrm{line number} + 2}{2}\rfloor^2\cdot 2\$ and subtract it from AL.
- If the result is positive, jump back to repeat, moving to the next line.
- Otherwise, add a net +18 to AL and return.

Special cases are handled as follows:

- `sub al, -15` is used to check for being in the extracted block and reused to adjust the horizontal position for elements in that block.
- That check gives a false positive for elements 21 and 39 (the only ones in column 3). That is corrected for by looking at the parity flag after `inc edx`; the incremented value is 5 (101<sub>2</sub>) or 6 (110<sub>2</sub>), with even parity, for elements 21 and 39, whereas it is 7 (111<sub>2</sub>) or 8 (1000<sub>2</sub>), with odd parity, for elements that do belong in the extracted block.
- Helium (2) is dealt with by `.byte 0xA9, 0xFE`, which subsumes the following two instructions into a `test eax, 0x023C42FE`. The following `be` condition is (CF or ZF); CF is always 0 after a `test`, and in this case, ZF is 1 only for element 1.

Comment: Windows 32-bit calling conventions return 64-bit structs in EDX:EAX.  But i386 SysV only does that for `int64_t`, not for structs larger than 4 bytes, unfortunately.  Apparently regparm doesn't change return values, just arg passing.  https://godbolt.org/z/811E7srM1 confirms that MSVC normal and `-Gv` (vectorcall) returns a struct in EDX:EAX, but regparm only returns in registers for a 64-bit integer type.  (And BTW, nice trick with `test eax, imm32` consuming 2 instructions on loop entry *and* doing useful FLAGS setting.  Your asm source can use meaningful label names and comments, though.)

Comment: Yeah, Agner's table 7 seems to be wrong, saying "GNU" compilers targeting 32-bit will return in "I" (integer registers) for a small struct.  Maybe he's looking at GCC targeting Windows?  But he says "Gnu except MacOS" implying that it covers Linux, and says MacOS also returns small structs in registers.  I think MacOS uses i386 SysV for 32-bit code, so yeah, that table has some errors.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 124 bytes

```
def f(n):
    for m,z in zip(b'hYWH97%\x13\r\x0b\5\3\2\1',b'*,\x0f)+\x0e\r\x0cw\x0bv\n\xa2\t'):
        if m<=n:return z%9+1,z//9+n-m
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RZXNbtNAFIV3SM1TDIsqCXHp_P9UdM8bICRvKNiqJeJEqQuhwJOw6QZegieBpyFzzzHdRP7s6J7vjJOZH7_2X6bb3fj4-PN-6i_yn28ful71q3F9tTjrdwe1bR7UMKqHYb-6Wd6-ffO6pPP2aFx7aI_6pg2ta21rls3N8kVzutOvN6fPTp6-_1y_8qkd2-M7207LOvJs6NX21fV4deim-8Np7nnZmObh8rJsxostHP4--9197LbdON2pa_XVXKmVaZRZNwtleZ0ruBNYPvC4tvU68L6rEAm-QiKECpkQKxRCqmA0SWJMFXDMMRYgQcbxiSQZT5IoE0iSZSJJwkwiIS2TkFZN_FxXAyTNGoCEWQuQLOsAEmU9QJJsAEiQjQDJsQlQBDJDtdCsIA6ODkYkHCVQ2dEClR01UNnRA5UdRVDZ0YTvsaoEVnYZgLQCkDCvAZLlDUCivAVIkncACfIeIDk-AKSyjwyVyn5WwI-JDqjsKYHKgRaoHKiByoEeqBwogsqBJqgcqkpk5RAB-PFWk8yWIQMwvQBkeNQAmR0NQEZHC5CW0QHQMnqSxMZAktwYSfjX0AItIzXQMtIDLRNF0DLRBC2TRTH89xxAZiQPwAguBiZwMTAgAaRLylwz6ZIKSbpkTZIu2ZCkS6YFumRqcA-gB7rk-a2ISaYJuuSqkvjGcgYgrZoUtiwaINOLAWCHsQCZXRxARhcPkJYlANCyRJLElkSS3JJJ0rLQgruPpge3H00T7j-aLvN2RxvuQNqjHScFEAdFEOdwUTiGq8IpBVSwh2ounwYaIjZV2VXTXMzIvpr-76uGPqxmKMRqhkasZub3BCdDp1O174tFPdCGRu1UPdLmM-blMHXbu1U9nY6n86ZfDetFPaaO6vm12tUza38Yxklu87J-54l2T5frswXOsPk8_Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
ＮθＩＥ↨⁺θ⊟⊟ΦＩ⪪⪪”←＆“▷/»h⦄¤Ａh)｜J\-w~~∕↔AＸ”¶¦ ‹⊟ιθ¹⁸⁺ικ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7LCsIwELz7FUtOCURomj7pTUEQVApec4lSMBjTtEn9/bgtuLAzszsDu8@Xnp@jtimdnV/ibfk8hplOrNv1s3GRHnWI9Ko9Pegw0N4ugU4c@tHTtU/GRoxvobu35o9E1JApJyUI5QoJhXIl6ly5NoOyQqeFGq26gqZRLi9BZJJwIMoRhgSEIV2GELYzBoeJrcVBNAjbH4bDe911KbV52n/tDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

```
Ｎθ                              Input as a number
             ”...”              Compressed lookup table
            ⪪     ¶             Split on newlines
           ⪪                    Split each element on space
          Ｉ                     Cast to integer
         Φ                      Filtered where
                       ι        Current pair
                      ⊟         Remove last element
                     ‹          Is less than
                        θ       Input number
        ⊟                       Get last matching element
       ⊟                        Get first element
     ⁺                          Plus
      θ                         Input number
    ↨                           Base conversion (i.e. divmod)
                         ¹⁸     Literal integer `18`
   Ｅ                       ⁺ικ  Increment the second element
  Ｉ                             Cast to string
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rust Nightly, 239 bytes + `#![feature(exclusive_range_pattern)]`

```
|p:u32|match p{1=>(1,1),2=>(18,1),3|4|11|12=>(p%8-2,p/8+2),5..11|13..19=>((p-3)%8+11,(p-3)/8+2),19..57=>((p-1)%18+1,(p-1)/18+3),72..87|104..119=>((p-25)%32-11,(p-25)/32+5),87|88=>(p-86,7),57..72|89..104=>((p-25)%32+4,(p-25)/32+7),_=>(2,1)}
```

Basically just matches in some squares then uses some division and mod to format the remaining numbers.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3a588ea12237bca22368b1df6b3efd4)

The actual original data is 236 bytes (118 * 2) so this code is actually barely longer than the data it's trying to encode. I tried I guess :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 32 bytes

```
₀f»#tṪİ□»₆τʀ»₃¡s↳‡∴»⁺/τ+Jf18vḋ›i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoBmwrsjdOG5qsSw4pahwrvigobPhMqAwrvigoPCoXPihrPigKHiiLTCu+KBui/PhCtKZjE4duG4i+KAumkiLCIiLCI1NyJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
₀f»#tṪİ□»₆τʀ»₃¡s↳‡∴»⁺/τ+Jf18vḋ›i
₀f                               # Push ten converted to a list of digits: [1, 0]
  »#tṪİ□»                        # Push compressed integer 145680302990
         ₆τ                      # Convert to base-64 as list: [2, 7, 43, 14, 16, 14, 14]
           ʀ                     # Convert each to a range [0, item]
            »₃¡s↳‡∴»             # Push compressed integer 180810357611003
                    ⁺/τ          # Convert to base-148 as list: [17, 30, 48, 129, 93, 147, 111]
                       +         # Add the values in these two lists at the same positions
                        J        # Join the [1, 0] and this list together
                         f       # Flatten this list
                          18vḋ   # Divmod each by 18
                              ›  # Increment each
                               i # 0-based index the input into this list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 113 bytes

```
\(x,p=matrix(c(1,0:-15,2:4,0:-9,5:12,0:-9,13:56,0,72:88,0,104:118,0:-2,57:71,0:-2,89:103),9,,T))which(p==x,T)[1,]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEWvk8AvZJLGJAO5hbhRF1Ja2oWopWLxKm6q4KG8jYlx9d_wmf8ez3F5dfF9nbrKfy47MeMcj4dpHGbRCILiiiw015kCLJMuRIbtCgpOs_cpSdVM5HOpYR07KugDkzISAVhLeeuHphfnGOd0bQn7v9hs2mY6jcO9FZ38iTV0QJ2mPGzyOqRBl-cQssxIWV6XpeQX)

Creates the matrix, then looks up values. Trying to redefine `+` so I can write

```
\(x,`+`=\(x)0:-x,p=matrix(c(1,+15,2:4,+9,5:12,+9,13:56,0,72:88,0,104:118,+2,57:71,+2,89:103),9,,T))which(p==x,T)[1,]
```

Is 116 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 79 bytes

```ruby
->n{j=0
"hilt8GXg".bytes{|i|n>i%104&&M=n+"+^9lG=3#"[j-=1].ord}
[M/18-1,M%18+1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOsvWgEspIzOnxMI9Il1JL6myJLW4uiazJs8uU9XQwERNzdc2T1tJO84yx93WWFkpOkvX1jBWL78opZYr2lff0ELXUMdX1dBC2zC29r@GoZ6eoaGFpl5uYgHIjIKizLwShUxrhQKFtOhMoAIA)

Uses 1 based indexing per the question, and comes out the same length as a couple of other answers.

The approach is similar to Arnauld's but I use a magic string and loop to iterate through all the discontinuities. The character is taken `mod 104` to be able to cover all the values from 0 to 103 without the need to use nonprintable characters.

The raw output is stored in `M` (use a capital letter for a consonant, to avoid Ruby saying it can't find a variable that was defined inside a loop.) A second magic string is used to look up the correct offset.

The output is given as row `M/18-1` (the `-1` is used to avoid offsets smaller than ASCII 32 in the magic string) and column `M%18+1` (`+1` is used because the columns are 1-indexed.)